# How to re-size an image not proportionaly?

Tags: android, height, width

I'm trying to make a game like a "click & kill" and I'm trying to make a health bar for the character to kill.
I'm using a simple image (a red rectangle) and I would like to reduce the health bar after one click. What I tryed works but the problem is not just the with decrease, the height too. So the result is really horrible. To begin, this is my XML (I only show one for example):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="33">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:id="@+id/hole4"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/healthBar4"
        android:src="@drawable/health_bar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So here nothing bad (I think) I leave `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` because I thought the problem came from here.
Next is my Activity :

```
final int healthBarHeightInitial = healthBar4.getLayoutParams().height;
final int healthBarWidthInitial = healthBar4.getLayoutParams().width;
healthBar4.requestLayout();

//ivHole4 is my ImageView I get the click to leave some life to the character
ivHole4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //If character die (works great).
        if(choixAction.ChoixAction(CharaHole4,outil)){
            Log.d("Perso","Character is die");
            mAvancement +=1;
            ivHole4.setImageResource(0);
            CharaHole4 = null;
            placeChara.setHole4(true);
            healthBar4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            healthBar4.getLayoutParams().height = healthBarHeightInitial;
            healthBar4.getLayoutParams().width = healthWidthInitial;
        }
        //if character don't die (here is the problem !)
        else {
            healthBar4.getLayoutParams().width = healthBar4.getWidth()/2; //This is works great
            healthBar4.getLayoutParams().height = healthBarHeightInitial; //This is do nothing, the height is /2 too.
            healthBar4.requestLayout();
        }

    }
});
```

I hope someone know how to change the image size not proportionally.
Thank's advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding this to your ImageView? : `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: It works !! =) Thank's a lot !! Post a new message if you want I put your answer the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ImageView` in the XML Layout needs to set the scale type to `fitXY` to allow it to expand without keeping proportions.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Picasso Library and set Crop Center.**